# C# MVC 4 ASP.net, How to Insert File into Database store in (binary)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httppostedfilebase

Would someone mind to guide me, how to save file into my database, and also retrieve it if possible,
I still new to this C# and MVC 4.
my databse Assignment contain a attribute call FileLocation which is varBinary ( MAX) .

### **Model**

```
 public partial class Assignment
{
    public Assignment()
    {
        this.CourseAvailables = new HashSet<CourseAvailable>();
    }



    public string AssignmentID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SubmissionDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Range(0,100, ErrorMessage="Only Value between 0-100 is accepted.")]
    public Nullable<decimal> Mark { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CourseAvailable> CourseAvailables { get; set; }
}
}
```

### **Control**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Assignment assignment)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Assignments.Add(assignment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(assignment);
    }
```

### **View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Assignment",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
...
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileLocation, new { type="file"})%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileLocation) %>
</div>
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a bit more processing here. Uploaded files come in as a `HttpPostedFileBase`, not a `byte[]` so you need to get the `byte[]` from the HttpPostedFileBase's InputStream, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Assignment assignment)
{
    if(Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count == 1)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, file.ContentLength);
            assignment.FileLocation = content;

            // the rest of your db code here
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Create");    
}
```

P.S. That model looks suspiciously like an Entity object. It's a tremendously bad idea to use Entity objects as your models. Try making an intermediary model and using that to render your data instead.

## Edit

In your view, change this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileLocation, new { type="file"})%>
```

to this:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

The error you're getting is because the model binder is mistakenly trying to bind your FileLocation field on the page (HttpPostedFileBase type) to the FileLocation field in your model (byte[] type).

Comment: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

this error occurs when I try this code

Comment: do you know what caused that error?
my DB attribute is varbinary(MAX)
and Model is byte[]

Comment: @WeakestInCoding Do you know on what line of the code the error occurs? And can you show me your whole method as it's written now?

Comment: I write exactly Like above, and when I save the file, the error occurs,

Comment: @WeakestInCoding See my edit above for the likeliest solution.

Answer (score 2):

In Asp.Net MVC we have to use `HttpPostedFileBase` for Uploaded files as shown below :-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Assignment assignment, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  if (file != null)
        {
            int byteCount = file.ContentLength;   <---Your file Size or Length
            .............
            .............//You can store file in database//
        }
 return RedirectToAction("Create");    
}
```

Comment: Then How do I store into the database next? 
like this? 
assignment.FileLocation = byteCount;
              
                db.Assignments.Add(assignment);
                db.SaveChanges();

Comment: @WeakestInCoding...above answer shown is basic concept of saving file .. for complete usage ...http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/aX9D090113-File-upload-with-strongly-typed-view-and-model-validation.html

Comment: @WeakestInCoding....just refer this post here....http://bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/11/16/Upload-and-Download-files-in-database-using-MVC-Linq-to-SQL.aspx